# Troubles with html-forms

Tags: php, html, forms, action

**index.php:**

```
    <form action="update_db.php" method="post">
    <?php
        require_once 'modules/' . $currentModule . '.php';
    ?>      
    </form>
```

**modules/*some_module*.php**

```
...
<input type="submit" />
...
```

**update_db.php:**

```
@extract( $_POST );
print_r( $_POST );
```

After loading index.php i see need form. But during submitting i'm coming to the same page (index.php). Why?

---

http:/****/admin/

Here is html-code generated: http://dpaste.com/93396/

---

It's so strange, but form generates 2 times... I removed all part of code and rewrited it. Now everything is fine. Thanks all.

Comment: You should look at the html source code that is sent to browser, and post that here.

Comment: When you view the source of the HTML in index.php, does the form look well-formed?

Comment: How can i mark my question as solved, if other guys didn't help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at your site. Your form action is index.php and that is why you keep seeing the same page after you click submit. If your code above is correct, ensure that you do not have `<form>` tags in your module containing the submit button.

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<table align="center">

    <tr>
        <td>Логин: </td>
        <td><input type="textfield" name="login" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Пароль: </td>
        <td><input type="password" name="password" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td align="right"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="вход" /></td>
    </tr>
<table>
</form>
```

Comment: And that page isn't need. It's just login-window. The next will be that, what I need

Comment: the problem isn't in the login, but on the next page. taht's what he's trying to say. (the form with 6 inputfields)

Comment: In original form element action attribute has different value (update_db.php) then above. And here is the problem. Set proper action value and it will work. Redirect could drop values of form.

Answer (score 0):

you have this:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
```

not this:

```
<form action="update_db.php" method="post">
```

Change it and your form will post to `update_db.php`